# SHA1+RSA - Help using Botan in C++

Tags: c++, encryption, sha, botan

I'm developing a WebService client in C++ for "Electronic Invoice" in Argentina. The webservice client and the xml treatment is not a problem but the cryptographic part give some headache (I'm quite new in this topic).

I'm reading the Botan documentation and found an example somewhat similar to what I need but I'm having difficulties adapting it.

I need to encrypt the XML in SHA1+RSA using the certificates and encode the result in Base64.

The official documentation provide examples in many languages unfortunately C++ is not one of them, I use the php example as start point to create my PoC code in C++.

The exact problem is this.

I have this XML example:

```
<loginTicketRequest version="1.0"><header><uniqueId>1560949868</uniqueId><generationTime>2019-06-19T10:10:08-03:00</generationTime><expirationTime>2019-06-19T10:12:08-03:00</expirationTime></header><service>wsfe</service></loginTicketRequest>
```

this XML became in this Base64 string

```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```

using this PHP function

```
  $STATUS=openssl_pkcs7_sign("TRA.xml", "TRA.tmp", "file://".CERT,
    array("file://".PRIVATEKEY, PASSPHRASE),
    array(),
    !PKCS7_DETACHED
    );
```

Where `CERT` and `PRIVATEKEY` are the public and private keys, `PASSPHRASE` is an empty string and the file TRA.xml contains the XML example provided above.

You can download the public and private key from this link
[Example Certificates](http://wget%20https://www.sistemasagiles.com.ar/soft/pyafipws/reingart.zip)

**Botan Example in C++**

```
#include <botan/pkcs8.h>
#include <botan/hex.h>
#include <botan/pk_keys.h>
#include <botan/pubkey.h>
#include <botan/auto_rng.h>
#include <botan/rng.h>
#include <iostream>

int main (intargc,char*argv[])
{
    if(argc!=2)
        return1;
    std::string plaintext("Your great-grandfather gave this watch to your granddad for good luck. Unfortunately, Dane's luck wasn't as good as his old man's.");

    std::vector<uint8_t> pt(plaintext.data(),plaintext.data()+plaintext.length());
    std::unique_ptr<Botan::RandomNumberGenerator> rng(newBotan::AutoSeeded_RNG);

    //load keypair

    std::unique_ptr<Botan::Private_Key> kp(Botan::PKCS8::load_key(argv[1],*rng.get()));
    //encrypt with pk
    Botan::PK_Encryptor_EME enc(*kp,*rng.get(), "EME1(SHA-256)");
    std::vector<uint8_t> ct = enc.encrypt(pt,*rng.get());
    //decrypt with sk
    Botan::PK_Decryptor_EME dec(*kp,*rng.get(), "EME1(SHA-256)");
    std::cout << std::endl << "enc: " << Botan::hex_encode(ct) << std::endl << "dec: "<< Botan::hex_encode(dec.decrypt(ct));

    return 0; //Edited :D, Thanks jww
}
```

I need to encrypt the XML in SHA1+RSA using the certificates and encode the result in Base64. Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: *＋1* for Botan. I think it is a good choice for this problem. `return0;` won't compile. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: the "return0;" was a typo when I created the post.
Still I have no idea how to build an example reading the X509 certificates and sign the XML with it using SHA1+RSA.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit confused about your main question. Guess you have to mention it more obvious. But as I noticed the problem is how to encrypt using your public RSA key and `SHA-1` hash function! (Am I right?)

So in that case I would say the `EME1(SHA-256)` that you could see in encryptor/decryptor objects aren't the bulk encryption algorithm and hash function used for encryption. They are padding algorithms!

In Botan there are **tls_channel** and **tls_callbacks** which handle the whole process of encryption and decryption between two sides. Take a further look at them.

Also if Botan is not mandatory I suggest you to use **Openssl** in `evp.h` file the function `EVP_SealInit` will may help you by letting pick your desired algorithm with `const EVP_CIPHER *type` input. For more info [check this link](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/EVP_SealFinal.html)